# How to add something to an element of an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add a grade to my arraylist object, when I tried to add two different grades to two different arraylist objects, evetything looks okay but when I try to print both objects, it prints like both grades belongs to same object. You will understand when you see the sample execution.

This is in my main method.

```
Student s1 = new Student("Cuneyt Cakir", "Istanbul", 35);
Student s2 = new Student("Halis Ozkahya", "Yalova", 28);
Student s3 = new Student("Mustafa Kamil Abitoglu", "Antalya", 20);
s1.addGrade(15);
s1.addGrade(89);
s1.addGrade(26);
s1.addGrade(44);
s2.addGrade(33);
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
```

The result is:

> Name: Cuneyt Cakir / City: Istanbul / Age: 35
>   Grades: [15, 89, 26, 44, 33]
>   Name: Halis Ozkahya / City: Yalova / Age: 28
>   Grades: [15, 89, 26, 44, 33]

This is my add method in Students class:

```
public static void addGrade(int grade) {
    if(grade>=0 && grade<=100){
        grades.add(grade);
    } else
        System.out.println("Invalid grade.");
}
```

This is another part of Student class:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> grades=new ArrayList<Integer>();

public Student(String value1, String value2, int value3) {
    name=value1;
    city=(value2);
    age=(value3);
}
```

And I'm getting grades with this code:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getGrades() {
    return grades;
}
```

The expected output is:

> Name: Cuneyt Cakir / City: Istanbul / Age: 35
>   Grades: [15, 89, 26, 44]
>
> Name: Halis Ozkahya / City: Yalova / Age: 28
>   Grades: [33]

Comment: Remove `static` and learn to create and handle different instances of your classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because `grades` is a static variable. Remove 'static' keyword to create a new ArrayList instance for each object.

Static variables in a class are common to all objects. So `grades' variable is common to all S1, S2 and S3 instances.

Comment: Because 'addGrades' method is a static method. Static method can't reference instance variables. So remove 'Static' from 'addGrades' method also.

Answer (score 1):

Remove static modifier,

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> grades=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Change to,

```
public ArrayList<Integer> grades=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Static modifier makes "grades" a class member. Removing static makes it an instance member